# How to extract values with GPath from RestAssured map response?

Tags: json, rest-assured, gpath

Having the following JSON response, how can I get a list of items `foo` and `bar` or values of `zoneGroup` under each element using GPath or RestAssured built-in JsonPath?

```
{
  "priceZones": {
      "foo": [
          {
              "zoneGroup": "foo",
              "code": "id1"
          }
      ],
      "bar": [
          {
              "zoneGroup": "bar",
              "code": "id2"
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

I tried `priceZones.*.[*].zoneGroup` [JsonPath Evaluator](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/), but get an error that RestAssured doesn't accepts `*` as a wildcard.

Comment: Do you just want to extract the values and store it in a variable or assert them ?

Comment: @WilfredClement I want to assert them against an array I have.

Comment: For response containing complex json, using de-serialization would be an advantage over writing jsonpath.